# pass string to jquery dialog to become name of the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For the purpose of globalization I need to translate buttons in jquery dialog, but when I try to pass variable I don't get value of variable, just name of it.

```
    var RemoveDialogButton = "@FriendsNamesNS.FriendsNames.Remove";
    var CancelDialogButton = "@FriendsNamesNS.FriendsNames.Cancel";

   //alert(RemoveDialogButton);

   $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height:190,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
        RemoveDialogButton: function() {
             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $('#yesno').click();
            return true;
        },
        CancelDialogButton: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RemoveDialogButton: {
      click: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          $('#yesno').click();
          return true;
      },
      text: RemoveDialogButton
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var buttons= {};
 buttons[your text] = function() { ....};


 $('.selector').dialog({      
   buttons: my_buttons 
  });
```